# Rolling Median with subset building over time

Tags: r, median

I would like to compute a variant of rolling medians on my dataset that does build the subsets not by going `k` observerations to the front and back, but by taking all observations into account that are in a given time window.

A straightforward implemtation could look like this:

```
windowwidth <- 30
median.window <- function(x) median(mydata[time <= x + windowwidth /2 & time >= x - windowwidth /2)
vapply(time, median.window)
```

However, as you can imagine, this is not very efficient for large datasets. Do you see a possible improvement or a package providing an optimized implementation? You can not expect the observations be distributed equally over time.

`zoo` provides `rollmedian`, but this function does not offer to choose the winwod based on time but on the observation count.

Comment: If you add a toy dataset, that would help raising interest. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Since the "timestamp" for each observation is essentially, from your description, random, there is no a priori way to determine which observations fit into a given window.  That said, I wonder whether using `outer()` with an appropriate time-width sort of function might at least build you a complete set of windowed sample sets.  I'll have to go off and play with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try this:

```
Rgames: timeseq<-1:5 
Rgames: winmat <- outer(timeseq,timeseq,FUN=function(x,y) y>=x &y<=x+2) 
Rgames: winmat 
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
[2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
Rgames: winmat %*% timeseq 
     [,1] 
[1,]    6 
[2,]    9 
[3,]   12 
[4,]    9 
[5,]    5
```

Replace that function with your window width and I think you'll be all set.
Edit: In respons to Thilo's query, it looks like in the general case you should use `apply`.  Given the stuff above, call your observation values "timval", as

```
Rgames: timval<-c(3,4,2,6,1)
Rgames: valmat<-timval*t(winmat)
Rgames: valmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    0    0    0    0
[2,]    4    4    0    0    0
[3,]    2    2    2    0    0
[4,]    0    6    6    6    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1
Rgames: apply(valmat,2,median)
[1] 2 2 1 0 0
```

Edit again: clearly I was asleep there: nobody wants a median based on all those zeroes.  I should think more before posting.  Add this:

```
valmat[valmat==0]<- NA
apply(valmat,2, median, na.rm=T)
[1] 3.0 4.0 2.0 3.5 1.0
```

And I'm sure there's a cleaner way of 'building'  `valmat` than this, but the final result is the "filter matrix" you want to apply any function to.

Comment: +1 -- Very nice. I always appreciate the elegance of `outer`-based solutions!  (BTW, hope you don't mind my edit to your answer. I only did it b/c I knew you could change it back if you do.)

Comment: Hmph- whatever you edited is not immediately obvious to the unaided eye :-), so I can hardly complain.

Comment: If you're ever interested in looking at edits, you can see them by clicking on the 'edited X hour/day ago' link above the editor's name (here Josh O'Brien). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Carl. However, how can I get the median based on this solution? I see how to compute rolling means, but for medians my first thought is that I would still be required to use one of the apply functions, now with precomputed filters. Did you have another idea in mind?